# How to add a contributor to a TFS2010 project via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, tfs

How do I add a contributor to a TFS2010 project via PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watching the powershell documentation (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools\Help\PowerShellCmdlets.mht), it looks like there is no option to add users to groups in TFS. But if you have the TFS Power Tools installed, you can use the tfssecurity tool in the command line.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>tfssecurity /?
[...]
    /g+ groupIdentity memberIdentity (/collection:CollectionURI | /server:ServerURI)
        Adds a user or a group to an existing group.
[...]
Identity Specifiers:

    sid:sid - References the identity with the specified SID.
        Example:   sid:S-1-5-21-2127521184-1604012920-1887927527-588340

    n:[domain\]name - References the identity with the specified name. For Windows, name is the  logon name. If the referenced identity is in a domain, the domain name is required.  For application groups, name is the group display name and domain is the URI or GUID of the containing project. In this context, if domain is omitted, the scope is assumed to be collection-level.
        Example: To reference the identity of the user "John Peoples" in the domain "Datum1" at the fictitious company "A. Datum Corporation, you would use the following syntax:
            n:DATUM1\jpeoples
        Example: To reference application groups, you could use either of the following syntaxes:
            n:"Full-time Employees"
            n:00a10d23-7d45-4439-981b-d3b3e0b0b1ee\Vendors
[...]
```

So it would look like:

```
tfssecurity /g+ [ProjectName]\Contributor Domain\UserName /collection:http://yourTfs:8080/ProjectCollection
```